# How to know if a method is virtual in visual studio without deeply checking its base classes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Any convenient method to know if a method is virtual in visual studio without deeply checking its base classes.

Comment: +1. I think if you hover over function, it may suggest, for VC++ IDE support is not as good as for C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the `override` specifier on any virtual method. It is supported in visual studio since VS2010. It helps you to avoid errors (such as misspelling an override or wrong parameter types) and clearly marks every virtual function as such.